# SQL conditional on another table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am pretty new to this so I hope this is clear. How do I get the data from one table, based on 1 month before the month in another table? Example with 2 tables. Using SQL.

First Table_A: Members, amount spent each month. Primary key composite of Name+Month

```
+---------+--------+--------+    
|  Name   | Month  | Amount |   
+---------+--------+--------+   
| James   | 202001 |     10 |   
| James   | 202002 |      5 |   
| James   | 202003 |      8 |   
| Michael | 202001 |      3 |   
| Michael | 202002 |      4 |   
| Michael | 202003 |      5 |   
| Michael | 202004 |      6 |    
| Tom.... | 202001 |     12 |   
| Tom.... | 202002 |     10 |   
| Tom.....| 202003 |      7 |   
| Tom.... | 202004 |      2 |   
+---------+--------+--------+
```

Second Table_B: Members and month unsubscribed. Primary key is Name.

```
+--------+--------+    
|  Name  | Month  |    
+--------+--------+    
| James  | 202003 |    
| Tom....| 202004 |    
+--------+--------+
```

Final output_table: Members and amount 1 month before unsubscribing + current members latest month amount and their status. Primary key should be Name.

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+    
|  Name   | Month  | Amount |    Status    |    
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+    
| James   | 202002 |      5 | Unsubscribed |    
| Tom     | 202003 |      7 | Unsubscribed |    
| Michael | 202004 |      6 | Subscribed   |    
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky.  I think this does the trick:

```
select t1.*, t2.amount,
       (case when t2.name is null then 'subscribed' else 'unsubscribed' end)
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by name order b amount desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.name is not null and seqnum = 2 or
      t2.name is null and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Though I used order by month instead of amount

Answer (score 0):

CTE approach,

```
with unsubscribed as(select 
first.name, first.month, first.amount 
from table1 first
  inner join table2 second
 on lower(trim(first.name)) = lower(trim(second.name))
 and first.month = second.month)
 ,
 subscribed as (select *, 
 case when  name not in (select distinct name from unsubscribed) then 'subscribed' 
 else 'unsubscribed' end as status from table1)

 select name,month,amount,status from (
 select *, row_number()over(partition by name order by month desc)as rn from subscribed 
 where (name,month) not in (select distinct name,month from unsubscribed)) where rn = 1
 order by month
```